# Change 2-digit year range into 4 digit list

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Background: I'm using Google tag manager to pass DOM elements as variables for a structured data set so products appear in google search with price, etc.

Our product landing pages have year ranges like this:

> 66-70

I want to return them like this:

> 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970

I've written a CJS variable that is using regex to find and replace the 2 digits with just some sample text. How can I generate the correct years?

````
var year_range = {{DOM | H1}};
var years = year_range.replace(/.[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]./, "Years Listed Here");
return years;   }```
````

Comment: create a function that does the same and returns in String format and use it as required.

Comment: What would that function look like?

Comment: remember to accept an answer after getting your doubt clear.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this

```
var input = "66-70"
var first = "19";
console.log(getYears(input,first)); //both same output
console.log(getYears("\n"+input)); //both same output

function getYears(range,first = "19") {
    var input = range.split("-");
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = parseInt(input[0]); i<=parseInt(input[1]); i++){
        if(i<10) ret+=first+"0"+i;
        else ret+=first+""+i;
        if(i==parseInt(input[1])) continue;
        else ret+=", ";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: First 3 lines are to run a sample test case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know that the years will always be in the 1900s, and that the format of the input string will always be `##-##`, then you can do something like this:

```js
const yearRangeToYearList = (yearRange) => {
    // split the input on the '-', parse both numbers and add 1900
    const [first, last] = yearRange.split('-').map((year) => {
        return parseInt(year, 10) + 1900;
    });
    // create an array of years and join it into a string
    return [...Array(last - first + 1)]
        .map((_, i) => {
            return first + i;
        })
        .join(', ');
};

// test the code (prints "1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970")
console.log(yearRangeToYearList('66-70'));
```

Comment: In our testing environment, most years ranges are two digits. In the live environment, they all are. And they all begin with '19'

Question: Google tag manager is saying I must define a function with a return value. How do I do that with your code?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. The function in this answer takes a string as an argument and returns a string already. Perhaps you could provide a bit more context.

Comment: This is the error I get from Google Tag Manager:

> Error at line 2, character 1: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: const declaration.

Comment: Oh, I see. You could try changing the JS version (I'm not familiar with Google Tag Manager) or you could switch the `const` to `var` instead. I would recommend always using the latest version of JS unless you have a specific reason not to (specific backwards-compatibility requirement). If you're using pre-2015 JS then you won't be able to use arrow functions, the spread operator, or const declarations, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm really new to JS, but my guess is that Google Tag Manager uses a stripped-down version of JS. I can't change the version, since it's built into the application.

Comment: GTM does not support ES6 in custom html tags and custom variables. However it would be much better in any case to use a custom template, since that avoids the use of eval (which GTM uses to run custom js), and also allows you to use ES6 features such as arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string and extract your numbers and then run a loop from start to end and add all the computed number in an array.

```js
const getRange = (str, prefix = '19') => {
  const result = [];
  let [start, end] = str.split('-').map(x => Number(x));
  while (start <= end) {
    result.push(`${prefix}${start}`);
    start++;
  }
  return result.join(",");
}

console.log(getRange('66-70'));
```

Comment: Hey Hassan, I need the years returned as a string for google tag manager.

Comment: Added `array#join()` to return string.